# declaration of ... as array of functions?

Tags: parsing, c++11

I am compiling some boost::python code and I don't understand this error:

```
namespace py=boost::python;
void func(py::tuple& t){
   /* ... */
   vector<shared_ptr<SomeClass>> vf=py::extract<vector<shared_ptr<SomeClass>>>(t[0])();
   /* ... */
}
```

with gcc 4.7, `-std=gnu++0x`:

```
error: declaration of 't' as array of functions
```

What is the proper way of writing the same? `py::extract<>(...)()` is a valid expression --

Comment: You can have an array of *pointers* to functions. You can't have an array of functions.

Comment: You didn't mistype the `=` sign did you?

Comment: If it helps any, `SomeType(t[0])();` would declare an array named `t` with zero length of functions which take no arguments and return `SomeType`.  I can't see how your code could be parsed that way, however.  Oh wait,  maybe...

Comment: Error sound like "most vexing parse". I don't know if it applies here, but i would throw extra parens around `t[0]` to see if it solves problem.

Comment: @zch: you got it, `py::extract<vector<shared_ptr<SomeClass>>>((t[0]))()` solved it! Can you put it as an answer so that I can accept it? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not even sure how the most-vexing parse can occur on the right hand side of copy-initialization... it usually applies to direct-initialization not using the new C++11 uniform initializer braces.

Answer (score 0):

Try separating end-template brackets with whitespace:

```
vector<shared_ptr<SomeClass> > vf=py::extract<vector<shared_ptr<SomeClass> > >(t[0])();
//                          ^                                             ^ ^
```

C++11 fixes this, but I'm not sure if your compiler version has the fix.

In C++03, your code would be parsed as containing bitshift `>>` operators, and then the whole blob `vector<shared_ptr<SomeClass>> vf=py::extract<vector<shared_ptr<SomeClass>>>` could somehow be mistaken for a function return type (now the `=` is inside a template argument, and therefore doesn't indicate copy-initialization).

Comment: No, gcc 4.7 has no trouble with `>>>`. The `=` is not inside the template argument.